# How to make the method for determine which order the list is sorted

Tags: groovy

I am currently making the method to check whether my list is in ascending or descending order.

I intend to make 2 method which is isAscend and isDescent to check which order the list is

```
class CheckOrderType {

    static def isAscend(){
        def list
        for(int i=0; i< list.size()-1; i++){
            if(list.get(i) < list.get(i+1)){
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    static def isDescend(){
        def list
        for(int i=0; i< list.size()-1; i++){
            if(list.get(i) > list.get(i+1)){
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }


    static void main(String[] args){
        def list = [5,3,2,1]
        if(list.isDescend()){
            print "True"
        }
        print "False"


    }
}
```

I expected it to return the True or False but it throw the exception

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Besides, you're calling static methods as if they were instance methods of List.

Comment: Hint: look carefully at the exception you got. It does not only tell you what went wrong, but also where it did happen in your program.

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is wrong. Also, do not return `true` value until the whole checking complete.

The following pseudo code just a roughly speaking which part of code you should modify:

isAscend()

```
For loop:
    If value[i] > value[i+1]:
        return false
    EndIf
EndLoop

return true
```

isDescend()

```
For loop:
    If value[i] < value[i+1]:
        return false
    EndIf
EndLoop 

return true
```

Comment: I fixed my code as you suggested, it work well with the list of ascending and descending order, but if I try this kind of list = [3,3,3] it will still throw that it is a descend list but not some error say that it is not sorted

Comment: @ThaiThanhNguyen Your are now using < to make the decision. 3 < 3 is not true. Therefore, the program will not execute return false. My pseudo code should based on your example list to modify. So, you should describe on your question clearly.

Comment: Really thank you, I have just see it with my own eyes, so sorry for the dumb question :(